# How to reshape numpy array with reorder?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1 x 2 x 3 array:

```
>>> a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])
>>> a
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
>>> a.shape
(1, 2, 3)
```

I want to reshape it to (3,1,2), but so that the elements along original dim 3 are now along dim 1. I want the result to look like this:

```
>>> new_a
array([[[1, 4]],
       [[2, 5]],
       [[3, 6]]])
```

and when I just use reshape, I get the the right shape, but the elements are in the same order, not what I want:

```
>>> a.reshape((3,1,2))
array([[[1, 2]],
       [[3, 4]],
       [[5, 6]]])
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
a.transpose(2,0,1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [347]: a
Out[347]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])

In [348]: a.transpose(2,0,1)
Out[348]: 
array([[[1, 4]],

       [[2, 5]],

       [[3, 6]]])
```

Alternatively :

With [`np.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) -

```
np.moveaxis(a,2,0)
```

With [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) -

```
np.rollaxis(a,2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, but `transpose()` is probably the easiest:

```
array.transpose(2,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import einops
einops.rearrange(x, 'x y z -> z x y')
```

And better use some meaningful axes names instead of `x`, `y`, `z` (like width, height, etc.)